# Cannot generate controller ,model or start rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I recently started getting problems in generating controllers,models and starting rails server in new projects. I am able to do all these things in old projects.

What can be done to resolve this error?

OS: Ubuntu 15.04 ,Ruby:2.1 ,Rails: 4.2.0

**Error Output**:

```
aditya@Aditya-PC:~/testRails/blog$ rails g controller  pages

Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00000002ec6c40> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/aditya/testRails/blog/config/application.rb:24:in `<class:Application>'
    from /home/aditya/testRails/blog/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:Blog>'
    from /home/aditya/testRails/blog/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

EDIT: I removed rails completely and again installed. But no effect, still having this error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run bundle install in  the application?

Comment: Yes, bundle install is running fine. But generating command and starting rails server are not working.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error seems like you created a new rails app without activerecord

> 'method_missing': undefined method 'active_record' for #Rails::Application::Configuration

the stack trace is hinting at `/home/aditya/testRails/blog/config/application.rb:24`

If removing activerecord is intentional follow along to remove anything that is related to activerecord, if not continue reading as you might figure out what went missing ;)

- remove any [activerecord config](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-record) from *application.rb* or *environments/**
- check your *config/application.rb* if 
  `require 'rails/all` is present, remove it and add the [railties](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/all.rb) that you need like:

  ```
  require "action_controller/railtie"
  require "action_mailer/railtie"
  require "active_job/railtie"
  require "sprockets/railtie"
  require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
  # require "railtie/active_record"
  ```
- remove any [adapter](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters) from the Gemfile (mysql2, pg, sqlite3)
- remove config/database.yml

Hope it helps :)

Comment: After doing what you said got this error while generating model: Error: **/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.1/lib/arel.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- arel/factory_methods (LoadError)**. I don't know how but now when I create a new project its working fine. I am still getting problems in the old projects that showed me these errors. New projects and projects before them are working fine.

Comment: Maybe Bundle install didn't worked properly for the projects that showed these errors.